# Webauthn configuration differences in Firefox

Tags: firefox, u2f, fido

I'm trying to understand what the different configuration elements mean in Mozilla Firefox. There was an announcement recently from Dropbox that they [had enabled support for WebAuthn](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2018/05/introducing-webauthn-support-for-secure-dropbox-sign-in/). I tried logging in-to DropBox using my U2F key that I'd registered through Chrome and it worked.

When I tried logging into Gitlab, however, it did not work. I had to explicitly enable `security.webauth.u2f`. So what's the difference in Firefox between these config elements?

`security.webauth.u2f`,`security.webauth.webauthn_enable_usbtoken`, and `security.webauth.webauthn_enable_softtoken`

My current assumption is that `security.webauth.*` is an implementation of Firefox's own authentication technology and `security.webauth.webauthn.*` is the implementation of [W3C's Web Authentication Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/) which also supports U2F. Is this assumption right?

Also, what's the difference between a `usbtoken` and a `softtoken`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand it (with help from [agl's blog post](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2018/03/27/webauthn.html)):

- `security.webauth.u2f` controls the original FIDO U2F API introduced by Chrome.
- `security.webauth.webauthn` controls the now-standard W3C WebAuthentication API.

They both let you talk to existing U2F (CTAP1) devices, but **using different JavaScript functions.** Webpages written for Chrome's "extension" API won't automagically know how to use WebAuthn, and vice versa.

That's the whole idea behind Dropbox's blog post: they had U2F *key* support for a long time already, but at first it only supported Chrome's API. Now it knows both APIs and detects which is available.

And for the devices themselves:

- `security.webauth.webauthn_enable_usbtoken` controls access to real U2F keys via USB HID.
- `security.webauth.webauthn_enable_softtoken` makes the browser *emulate* a U2F device, for development purposes (and probably without any security guarantees).

Comment: This answer clarified a lot of my doubts. Thanks @grawity! I'll have to google CTAP though. Just another clarification:

> Now it knows both APIs and detects which is available.

does this mean that when Google (and others) start supporting webauthn, the old U2F javascript-based auth capabilities will be redundant?

Comment: CTAP is the low-level protocol used by browsers (native desktop apps) to talk with FIDO keys. Original U2F-only devices use CTAP1, new "FIDO2" keys add CTAP2 with more capabilities. And yes, WebAuthn will make the original U2F API redundant.